# Creating an object from Arrays in Java

Tags: java

I have two lists and I am trying to create an object with the elements in this list.

for ex.

["John Wick" , "New York" , 530520 , 560999 ] and ["Alex Souza" , "Houston", 556895]

some lists may have 1 number, some may have more numbers.

how can i create?

Comment: Why do the lists have different elements, what does the target object look like?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Welcome to the Stacks.  Consider what you would use the "object" for.  That will help you decide whether to make a list of lists or one list in a similar format or an array of arrays or a set or Hashmap.  Please let us know what your goal is more clearly.  There seems some structure shared by the examples. Are they all `{ name, place, number(s) }` ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Where are these lists coming from?

Comment: Yes Alan, They are all { name ,place, number(s) } . Sorry for couldn't explain my problem clearly.

Comment: @Alan can you help me please

Comment: What exactly are your inputs? Files, strings, objects? Each has one line/record or multiple? You question is quite unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to:

1. Store these inputs in an ArrayList as Strings (So you don't have to define your length)
2. Take the ArrayList in as input for the Object construction
3. Parse the Strings to ints.

```
public class Obj {
  String name;
  String city;
  int[] num;
    
  public Obj(ArrayList<String> in){
    name = in.get(0);
    city = in.get(1);
    for(int i = 2; i < in.size(); i++){
      num[i-2] = Integer.parseInt(in.get(i));
    }
  }
}
```

allowing you to call

```
Obj o = new Obj(inArrayList);
```

to produce the object you require, with identifier `o` as an example.

Don't forget to import `java.util.ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

## Record

In Java 16+, the [records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) feature is a brief way to write a class whose main purpose is to communicate data transparently and immutably. You merely define the type and name of ea h member field. The compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`.

```
record Person ( String name , String city , List< Integer > numbers ) {}
```

Instantiate.

```
Person p = new Person( "John Wick" , "New York" , List.of( 530520 , 560999 ) ) ;
```

Collect.

```
List< Person > people = new ArrayList<>() ;
people.add( p ) ;
```

### Factory method

We can add a `static` factory method to convert your particular inputs into `Person` objects. We name our factory method `Person.of` per [naming conventions established](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/overview/naming.html) by the *java.time* framework.

The pseudo-ellipsis (triple FULL STOP characters) in `int... nums`  tells Java to allow zero, one, or more of a series of arguments of that type. The arguments arrive to us as an array of that type. So in our code we expect an array of `int`, an `int[]`. Passing that `int` array to `IntStream.of` produces a stream of `int` values. For each of those `int` values, we convert it from a primitive to an `Integer` object by calling `.boxed()`. Finally, we collect those `Integer` objects into a `List< Integer >` by calling `toList`. With a `List< Integer >` in hand, we can call the constructor of our `Person` record.

```java
package work.basil.demo;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public record Person(String name , String city , List < Integer > numbers)
{
    static Person of ( String name , String city , int... nums )
    {
        return new Person( name , city , IntStream.of( nums ).boxed().toList() );
    }
}
```

Usage:

```java
List < Person > people =
        List.of(
                Person.of( "John Wick" , "New York" , 530520 , 560999 ) ,
                Person.of( "Alex Souza" , "Houston" , 556895 )
        );
```

> people.toString() = [Person[name=John Wick, city=New York, numbers=[530520, 560999]], Person[name=Alex Souza, city=Houston, numbers=[556895]]]